# MySQL query for wind rose data

Tags: mysql, weather

I currently have a table called observations that is updated every minute with the following fields (amongst others);

```
time                  wind_speed_kn     wind_dir_deg
2014-12-13 13:34:22   12.3              23
2014-12-13 13:35:17   9.5               55
2014-12-13 13:36:32   12.7              288
...
```

I have a php loop that does the following query

```
set time_zone = "+9:30";
select speed_range, count(*) as count from 
(SELECT CASE 
  WHEN max_gust_kn < 0.1 THEN '0' 
  WHEN max_gust_kn > 0.1 and max_gust_kn <= 5 THEN '0-5' 
  WHEN max_gust_kn > 10 and max_gust_kn <= 15 THEN '10-15' 
  WHEN max_gust_kn > 15 and max_gust_kn <= 20 THEN '15-20' 
  WHEN max_gust_kn > 20 THEN '>20' 
END as speed_range from observations 
where (wind_dir_deg > 303.75 and wind_dir_deg < 326.25) and date(time) = date(now()))
as wind_summaries group by speed_range
```

Each time through the php loop the test for the degrees is changed so I get a result for each point on the compass (N, NNE, NE, ENE etc)

This is mostly working fine.. except that I sometimes get some NULL results that muck up my indexing.  Eg if I run it at the moment for one of the compass points I get the following;

```
speed_range     count
NULL            6
0               445
0-5             58
```

And when I render my windrose I count the first index for each direction as "calm" or "0" but this null value is mucking it up and the following indexes...

Any idea what is wrong with the query and how I can get rid of these NULL values?  I don't know sql that well and just copied examples from here to get the query working at all...

The end result of the windrose can be seen at http://weather.stormpilgrim.com/windrose.php if you want to see what I'm trying to achieve.  I think its all good except for this query.

Comment: 1. `SELECT * FROM observations WHERE max_gust_kn IS NULL`. 2. Also you have a gap `(5, 10]` in your `CASE`.

Comment: I do have NULL values in table for that field but not for today - so when I query "set time_zone = "+9:30";
select time, max_gust_kn, wind_dir_deg from observations where date(time) = date(now()) and max_gust_kn is NULL;" i get no results.

Comment: Doh!  How did i miss that gap... /sigh... thanks heaps zerkms

Answer (score 1):

The `NULL` value would be caused by values falling out of the `case` statement.  This is the subquery with the `case` statement:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN max_gust_kn < 0.1 THEN '0' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 0.1 and max_gust_kn <= 5 THEN '0-5' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 10 and max_gust_kn <= 15 THEN '10-15' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 15 and max_gust_kn <= 20 THEN '15-20' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 20 THEN '>20' 
       END) as speed_range
from observations 
where (wind_dir_deg > 303.75 and wind_dir_deg < 326.25) and date(time) = date(now())
```

The problem must be that `max_gust_kn` can be `NULL`.  You can either include this as a valid value:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN max_gust_kn < 0.1 THEN '0' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 0.1 and max_gust_kn <= 5 THEN '0-5' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 10 and max_gust_kn <= 15 THEN '10-15' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 15 and max_gust_kn <= 20 THEN '15-20' 
             WHEN max_gust_kn > 20 THEN '>20' 
             ELSE 'Missing'
       END) as speed_range
```

Or change the `where` to exclude this possibility:

```
where (wind_dir_deg > 303.75 and wind_dir_deg < 326.25) and
      max_gust_kn >= 0 and
      date(time) = date(now())
```

Comment: Yep the issue seemed to be simply the missing '5-10' range - how embarrasment! :)

Comment: @PaulThomsen . . . That is now obvious.